# Missing return in global function expected to return in for loop

Tags: swift, for-loop, scope

Can someone explain why I receive this error. It seems like a scope issue, but all my cases are covered by the else statement right?

```
func testNumber(number: Int) throws -> Int {
    for i in 1...100 {
        let x: Int = i * i
        if x == number {
            return x
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to understand why this error is occurring. The function is not important.

Comment: The function _is_ sort of important, because the example code is something no one would ever actually write. However, I've tried to answer to question as posed, all the same.

Answer (score 1):

The example is extremely silly because you are going to return `0` on the very first iteration of the loop, unless `number` happens to be `1`. You're not checking any other members of the loop sequence to see whether any of *them* satisfy the test. That's kind of ridiculous; your loop is completely pointless. You might as well have written:

```
func testNumber(number: Int) throws -> Int {
    return (number == 1) ? 1 : 0
}
```

And that is the reason for the compiler's behavior as well. No one would *ever* return on *every* wing of a condition inside a for loop, because the loop would always exit after the first iteration. So the compiler doesn't even bother to consider that possibility, because why should it?

If there had been no for loop, all would have been well, because the condition is at top level:

```
func testNumber(number: Int) throws -> Int {
    if number == 7 {
        return 7
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

But since the condition is buried in a for loop, the compiler just doesn't bother to dive in and study the `return` logic. Even the simplest example fails to compile:

```
func testNumber(number: Int) throws -> Int {
    for i in 1...100 {
        return 1
    }
} // error
```

Because, again, that is something no one would ever say.

If you are determined to keep the code you have, just quiet the compiler's uncertainty with a fatal error:

```
func testNumber(number: Int) throws -> Int {
    for i in 1...100 {
        let x: Int = i * i
        if x == number {
            return x
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
    fatalError("shouldn't get here")
}
```

But a more realistic rewrite of your (unrealistic) example would be this:

```
func testNumber(number: Int) throws -> Int {
    for i in 1...100 {
        let x: Int = i * i
        if x == number {
            return x
        }
    }
    return 0
}
```

That makes the compiler happy and gives the output that your original code probably intended.